# Suggestion for how you could handle multiple helpful answers

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Often, as other questions here discuss, you find yourself with one or two answers to your question that is *kinda* correct. But to be really correct they either need to be rewritten slightly, combined or something else. Or maybe they were not really correct at all, but set you of in the right direction.

I think it would be sweet if I could answer my own question (and mark it as accepted at once) and select other answers that were the helpful ones. My answers could then become the accepted one on the top (with no, or a very small amount of rep) and the ones I marked as helpful could be marked as helpful (with slightly less rep than a regular accepted one) and come right after it.

Rep for upvotes on the accepted answer could give a small amount of rep all the participants.

Comment: Dupe? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13413/how-do-i-combine-two-answers-to-create-the-best-answer-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Yeah, I read that one. That was a question about how it should be done at the moment. Mine is a suggestion for how it could be done in the future. Kinda :p

Answer (score 1):

You can already do that. Combine the answers in your own answer, accept your own, link to the others and tell people they should upvote these.

Comment: But I can't accept my own answer before 48 hours have passed. And telling people to upvote other answers I'm not sure if I like that much...

Comment: Why don't you like that? If you compose your own answer and you tell people it was composed out of these answers, then you can say: "if you like my answer, upvote the original ones. They deserve the honour, not me." And waiting 48 hours shouldn't be that hard either.

Answer (score 1):

Either do like John said or accept the best answer available and then give upvotes (and reasoning why in comments) on all the others that were also helpful.